# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_name'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, attributeerror

I get an odd error...here is my code in Python2.7:

```
 for key,value in pins_by_power.iteritems():
     print key.get_name()
```

The output is the the answers I want, plus an unwanted error:

```
im_mclkin
im_trig_eventin
im_trig_ubreak
it_bypass_sel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 80, in <module>
    key_name = key.get_name()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_name'
```

1. How can I get the answer plus an error? Unless that `AttributeError` is an exception?
2. How might I bypass the exception if it is such a thing?

Comment: Uh, what type of object are you expecting `key` to be for it to have a `key.get_name` method? Because apparently sometimes `key` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try` and `except` to avoid the `AttributeError`:

```
for key,value in pins_by_power.iteritems():
    try:
        print(key.get_name())
    except AttributeError:
        print('{} (type {}) has no attribute "get_name"'.format(key, type(key)))
```

The reason that you got some results is that these results have been `print`ed before you hit the Exception. Either in the `for`-loop or from earlier parts of your script.